# AWS cognito service user login performance test with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, aws

Im about to do a performance test to a user login using Jmeter.
I was able to record the initial reguests using Jmeter and at the 2nd request its genarating the Authorization key.

Inital request it, send data as on the below screen shot and Im getting some valid responses.

> https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/
>   [image]

At the 2nd request I have to pass few parameters like

> PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK  , PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE.

PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK is directly comming as a responce from 1st request, But the issue is to find PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE.
becouse its not available at the 1st responce.

So my quesction is where am i going to get this PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE in order to complete the 2nd request whcih will give me the authantication key.

Comment: Im also facing the same issue. is there a solution for this issue

Comment: Can any one provide complete code to create PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE??

Answer (score 2):

All AWS API requests has to be signed, the signature needs to be **calculated** on your side, you cannot extract it from the previous response, you need to generate it.

Check out [Signing AWS API Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) for more details.

In JMeter you can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to create the request signature according to the above algorithm and use the value as the `PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE` parameter.

Reference material:

- [How to Handle Dynamic AWS SigV4 in JMeter for API Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-dynamic-aws-sigv4-in-jmeter-for-api-testing/)
- [AWSCognitoSampleDeveloperAuthenticationSample](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample)